Expected first arrival times in poisson process.
Suppose we have two independent homogeneous Poisson processes $\text{HPP}(\lambda_1)$ and $\text{HPP}(\lambda_2)$. We denote $(N_t^1)_{t\geq 0}$ as the number of arrivals in $\text{HPP}(\lambda_1)$ and $(N_t^2)_{t\geq 0}$ as the number of arrivals in $\text{HPP}(\lambda_2)$ up to time $t\geq 0$. Conditioning on the event $\{N^1_t = 2\}$ for some $t \geq 0$, what is the conditional expectation of the first arrival time of the joint process?
My approach to the problem is that, conditioning on the event $\{N^1_t = 2\}$, we can use the order statistics property of the homogeneous Poisson process to determine the first arrival time, which is $\min(U_1, U_2)$, where both $U_1$ and $U_2$ are uniformly distributed on the interval $[0, t]$. Then we can calculate the expected time of the first arrival time in the joint process by calculating
$$
\text{E}(\min(S^2_1, \min(U_1, U_2))).
$$
My question is: is the above expectation the same if we calculate the distribution (or rather density) of $X = \min(U_1, U_2)$ first and then calculate $\text{E}(\min(S^2_1, X))$? If not, why? When I calculated them separately, the results were different, but that could just be some calculation errors that I haven't noticed yet.

Please edit your question tnclude a definition of $N_t^1$ in your question.  DO NOT provide the definition by writing a response to my request as a comment:. instead, click on the Edit button below your question and put the definition there into the question itself.

I would like to comment, my belief is that the two expectations should be the same since all 3 random variables that are in the first formulation are independent.

Conditioned on the event $N_t^1 = 2$, the variable $U_2$ is not necessarily defined on $[0,t]$ because there may be no events observed for the second process in that time interval, especially if $\lambda_1 \gg \lambda_2$.

Why would that be a problem, we are only looking for the minimum of the two functions and $ U_2 \sim U([0, t])$ so it can only take values on $[0, t]$. I don't understand your concern.

I agree that the two ways of calculating the expectation should give the same result.
